# Process accounting with acct structure in Unix

Tags: unix, process-accounting

I've read about the concepts of process accounting in Advanced Unix.
I understand that these accounting records are typically a small amount of binary data with the name of the command, the amount of CPU time used, the user ID and group ID, the starting time, and so on for a process.
But I don't understand how the `acct` structure can be accessed.

```
struct acct ac_data;
```

How can I access an `acct` structure and how can I enable and disable process accounting?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). What have you tried?

Comment: Do you mean Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment? I couldn't find a book called Advance Unix.

Comment: @DanielPorteous - Thank you, That i'm bit clear from your answer

Comment: @Harini Glad to help. If you found it helpful feel free to upvote/mark as accepted, and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's worth noting that on some systems the process accounting is disabled by default (I know it's disabled on my particular Linux system and on the latest macOS 10.12 by default). This is because logging with binary files is considered by many to violate the [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy), specifically this part:

> Write programs to handle text streams, because that is a universal interface.

With all of that said, there are a few main things you need to do:

1. **Turn on process accounting.** You can do this with the `acct(2)` command, I recommend you check out the manpages for your system but [here are some for Linux online](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/acct.2.html). You specify where you want to log to with this command, or use `NULL` to turn process accounting off.
2. **Read in the accounting records.** For this you need the `fread(3)` function, which reads in binary data from a file. Note that this isn't cross-platform because each system will likely have different fields for the `acct` struct (here you can see the problems with binary interfaces). Again, I highly recommend you read the manpages for `fread`, they're very clear about how to use it.
3. **Read the fields of the struct.** Once you've got the `acct` struct in your program, you can just access the fields like you would any other struct. To know which fields you can use, again, read the manpages. [This page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/acct.5.html) shows the fields on one particular system.

As you've probably noticed, a common theme here is to read the manpages. They're quite concise and I think it's a great way to piece together how a particular system works. Type in `man 5 acct` on your system and you'll have everything you need to know!